# I found woocommerce api authentication error for products access

Tags: woocommerce

I found {"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"oauth_consumer_key parameter is missing"}]} , when i want to access products from REST API in WooCommerce.

I am using this url http://domainname/wc-api/v2/products.

Please help me.

Comment: There is no question here

Comment: HI, I want to access rest api in WooCommerce , when i want to open orders in using this url http://www.domain.com/wc-api/v2/orders , it shows this error. "{"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"oauth_consumer_key parameter is missing"}]} "